# Выбрать объекты из бд по свойству (sqlalchemy, flask)

Tags: python, база-данных, веб-программирование, flask, sqlalchemy

У меня есть составная модель:

```
class Faculty(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Faculty: {self.title}>'

    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title


class Specialty(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    faculty_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('faculty.id'))
    faculty = db.relationship('Faculty', backref=db.backref('specialties', lazy=True))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Speicality: {self.faculty} {self.title}>'

    def __init__(self, title, faculty_id):
        self.title = title
        self.faculty_id = faculty_id
```

Я использую sqlalchemy, и пока всё что я нашёл близкое к тому, это команда `Specialty.query.filter_by()`, но я всё равно не пойму как через неё получить доступ ко внутренним членам поля, если же написать `Specialty.query.filter_by(Faculty.title='maths')`, то интерпретатор выдаёт ошибку. Как мне выбрать из бд все специальности, в которых название факультета допустим "maths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даже не зная какую конкретно ошибко вы увидели, можно транслировать это на SQL и такой запрос не будет работать, потому что у вас нет в выборке материнской таблицы - чистый sql тоже скажет, что не знает колонку `title`. Решить можно жойном: `Specialty.query.join(Faculty).filter_by(Faculty.title='maths')`